# Anyone knows the repository of "Traceroute For Linux"?

Tags: traceroute

```
TRACEROUTE(8)                Traceroute For Linux                TRACEROUTE(8)

NAME
       traceroute - print the route packets trace to network host

SYNOPSIS
       traceroute [-46dFITUnreAV] [-f first_ttl] [-g gate,...]
               [-i device] [-m max_ttl] [-p port] [-s src_addr]
               [-q nqueries] [-N squeries] [-t tos]
               [-l flow_label] [-w waittime] [-z sendwait]
               [-UL] [-P proto] [--sport=port] [-M method] [-O mod_options]
               [--mtu] [--back]
               host [packet_len]
       traceroute6  [options]
```

I want to see its source ,but can't find it anywhere...

Anyone knows the git/cvs/svn repository of "Traceroute For Linux"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/natty/traceroute

Comment: Thanks a lot! How do you find it, or do you just know it before hand?

Comment: The package repositories of various distributions are great places to find things like this, (as well as man pages and dependency information) and it's all just http! so you can browse it easily: http://packages.ubuntu.com

Comment: I just tried the link, seems both are dead...`git://git.debian-maintainers.org/git/daniel/traceroute.git` and `http://git.debian-maintainers.org/?p=daniel/traceroute.git`:(

Comment: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/traceroute/traceroute_2.0.15.orig.tar.gz ?

Comment: I want to find the repository, not archives,though..that way I can see the diffs.

Comment: ah, ok. this one is working:
git://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/traceroute.git

Comment: @MattSweeney *I want to see its source* in the questions means he want's to see **source code of original software [traceroute](http://traceroute.sourceforge.net/)**, no source code of packaging of any distro, nor package repository neither.